# Null check for CompletableFuture Object Array

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I am using CompletableFuture for one of my service as below -

```
CompletableFuture<Employee>[] employeeDetails =
        empIds.stream().map(empId ->
            employeeService.employeeDetails(Integer.valueOf(empId))).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
```

Internally EmployeeService call API which returns employee details.

Problem is when that API returns null or any exception then response is null. When I check for null always it false even if employeeDetails array is null and its values also null and I am getting Null Pointer.

I am checking null as -

```
if(employeeDetails != null && employeeDetails.length > 0){
   //This condition always true even if null values or null array.
   CompletableFuture<Void> allEmployeeDetails = CompletableFuture.allOf(employeeDetails); // Here I am getting NullPointerException
}
```

Am doing any mistake here or CompletableFuture array need to handle with any special check.

Comment: Yes. I am getting NullPointerException. As question is also updated where I am getting NullPointerException.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `CompletableFuture.allOf(employeeDetails)` throws

> NullPointerException if the array or any of its elements are null

You must check all the elements of the array, and only pass the not-null ones to `allOf`.

Or you can filter out the `null`s before you create the array:

```
CompletableFuture<Employee>[] employeeDetails =
    empIds.stream()
          .map(empId -> employeeService.employeeDetails(Integer.valueOf(empId)))
          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
          .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
```

This way your `if` statement should be sufficient.